# How to check for availability before automatic refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to update a webpage periodically and I want the browser only to update if the page is available. Right nov I'm using using this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval("location.reload()", 66000);
    });   
</script>
```

Is it possible **not to** update if the page for some reason isn't available?

Comment: location.reload() — yuk!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) check for a tiny resource ahead of time, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(maybeRefresh, 66000);

    function maybeRefresh() {
        $.ajax({
            url:     "/path/to/tiny/resource",
            type:    "GET",
            success: function() {
                // That worked, do the full refresh
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

...but I would tend to think you'd be better off just [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load)ing the updated content instead. Put all of the primary content in an element with the `id` `"main"`, then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#main").load("/path/to/new/content");
    }, 66000);
});
```

That replaces the content of the `#main` element with the content received from the `GET` to `/path/to/new/content`. If the `GET` fails, no update.

I would probably also use a chained `setTimeout` instead of a `setInterval` and handle errors by trying to refresh more aggressively. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(refresh, 66000);

    function refresh() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/path/to/new/content",
            type: "GET",
            success: function(html) {
                // Success, update the content
                $("#main").html(html);

                // Reload in 66 seconds
                setTimeout(refresh, 66000);
            },
            error: function() {
                // Failed, try again in five seconds
                setTimeout(refresh, 5000);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to update a RSS feed. Guess there will not be a lot of updated data. So maybe it will be okay to download all of it?

Comment: @user1950067: Up to you! You know a lot more about what you're doing than I do. :-) But yeah, it's a rare RSS feed that changes *hugely* in 66 seconds. If that's what you're doing, I'd lean toward that last example. No unnecessary `GET` operations, smooth from the user's perspective, you can even apply effects when updating `#main`...

Comment: I'm not shure I know a lot more about what I'm doing than you - it's mostly trial and error for my part :-) Thanx for your help - I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the HTML5 cache manifest feature. 
In order to do that, specify a manifest file path in your `html` element's `manifest` attribute:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
```

Then add all the website's resources to the manifest file, e.g.:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# v11
/index.html
/main/features.js
/main/settings/index.css
http://example.com/images/scene.jpg
http://example.com/images/world.jpg
```

Now, if you do a GET request for index.html, the browser will only do an actual request if the cache manifest file is available and it has changed (in order to force an update you can store a version number in cache manifest comment and update it when needed). Otherwise, the page will be reloaded from browser's cache.

Comment: Looks like a very smart solution but I'm afraid I cant use it. It's a RSS feed I'm updating.