# How to save a complete webpage and load later for offline access

Tags: android, webview

I have `WebView` and wanted to save some web pages to internal or external storage for offline access. Please provide some example if someone has already gone through this.

Comment: Hey .. how did you solve this query.. I have to implement something similar to this .your suggestion would be great .

Comment: well thanks to this guy https://github.com/gregko/WebArchiveReader for his library which helped me to load `WebArchive` saved as `xml`

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for achieve your task and check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670638/webview-load-website-when-online-load-local-file-when-offline) link :-

```
WebView webView = new WebView( context );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 5 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 5MB
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT ); // load online by default

if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) { // loading offline
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
}

webView.loadUrl( "http://www.google.com" );
```

**permission which require**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: I appreciated your answer but what i actually want is i want to give option to save that webpage and show in details in `ListView` like title ,for more details see the offline functionality of this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.world.newspapers

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the server-side, the best idea would be to use HTML5 cache manifest, as I described it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14348234/737885

If you don't, you can try simply caching it as HCD suggested, but that solution depends on HTTP headers, and other considerations, so it might not be bullet-proof.

An alternative solution would be to point the WebView to the URLs comprising the site by means of the WebViewClient callbacks (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) and downloading each resource manually using HttpClient. This is the only solution of the three, which creates a re-usable offline copy of the site. The other are based on the WebView cache so you can only use the cached copies inside the very same WebView.

Comment: The cache manifest is now deprecated, and it no longer works in some browsers. You can do this using a [Service Worker](https://deanhume.com/create-a-really-really-simple-offline-page-using-service-workers/) instead.